# Используется потенциально неинициализированная локальная переменная-указатель "matrix"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
int i, j, n, m;
char d;//для меню
float** matrix;//объявляем двойной указатель на матрицу

kt:
//    cout << "1- manual input "; 
cout << "1- ручной ввод ";
cout << endl;
cout << "2- ввод из файла ";
cout << endl;
cout << "3- выход ";
cout << endl;
cout << "введите: ";
cin >> d;
cout << endl;
if (d > '3' || d < '1')
{
    cout << "правильно выберите пункт меню и введите число ";
    cout << endl;
    goto kt;
}

if (d == '3') { return 0; }
if (d == '2') { ... }

if (d == '1') {//ручной ввод данных в матрицу
    cout << "Количество уравнений: ";
    cin >> n;//
    cout << "Количество переменных: ";
    cin >> m;//
    m += 1;
    //создаем массив
    float** matrix = new float* [n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { matrix[i] = new float[m]; }

    //инициализируем

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << " Элемент " << "[" << i + 1 << " , " << j + 1 << "]: ";

            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
//выводим массив
cout << "расширенная матрица" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        cout << matrix[i][j] << " "; // Здесь возникает ошибка из вопроса
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;
```

Комментарием отметил, где возникает ошибка (внизу кода). Как её исправить, почему она неинициализированна?

Comment: А что у вас будет в `matrix`, если `d` не равно `'1'`? Ветка с инициализацией окажется пропущена...

Comment: @Harry добавил код, посмотрите снова

Comment: Все равно будет та же ерунда — вдруг сначала будет введено 2? Вобщем, если вас смущает **исключительно** предупреждение — напишите `float** matrix = 0;`, и дело с концом. А если чтоб была защита от дурака, то думайте :) Например, если два раза подряд ввести 1, будет утечка памяти...

Comment: @Harry Это не предупреждение, а ошибка, которая не даёт запустить прогу.
Если поставить float** matrix = 0, то она запускается, но расширенная матрица не выводится

Comment: Это предупреждение, просто у вас, наверное, включена настройка "рассматривать предупреждения как ошибки". Что касается вывода-невывода... Вы об этом ничего не спрашивали, правда? *Как её исправить, почему она неинициализированна?* (орфография сохранена) Более того, я же намекал: *если вас смущает исключительно **предупреждение** — напишите `float** matrix = 0;`, и дело с концом. А если чтоб была защита от дурака, то думайте :)*

Comment: @Harry но если ошибка возникает как раз в выводе, то подразумевается исправление ошибки, чтобы матрица выводилась

Comment: Ту ошибку, о которой вы спрашивали, устранили. Для устранения новой нужна как минимум дополнительная информация, минимальный компилируемый воспроизводящий ошибку код etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну тут проблема с областью видимости и двойным объявлением переменной.
Вот в начале функции Вы объявляете `float** matrix;` - всё хорошо, всё логично.
А потом в при обработке выбора Вы объявляете ещё одну локальную переменную, выделяете память, инициализируете.

```
if (d == '1') //ручной ввод данных в матрицу
{
    //создаем массив
    float** matrix = new float* [n]; // вот тут объявляется новая переменная, это не та же самая переменная, что в начале функции!!!
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { matrix[i] = new float[m]; }
    //инициализируем
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << " Элемент " << "[" << i + 1 << " , " << j + 1 << "]: ";
            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
} // вот тут закончилась область видимости локальной переменной `float** matrix`, объявленной внутри оператора if
```

А потом у нее заканчивается область видимости, которая ограничена оператором `if`, и эта локальная переменная уничтожается. Выделенная память утекает.
И потом, когда Вы начинаете выводить массив, вы обращаетесь по адресу, записанному в переменную `float** matrix`, объявленную в начале функции. А она указывает в никуда, память не выделялась - у Вас появляется ошибка.
Лечится просто - в операторе `if` уберите объявление. Вот так:

```
if (d == '1') //ручной ввод данных в матрицу
{
    //создаем массив
    matrix = new float* [n];
```

И да, компилятор Вас правильно предупредил, эта переменная не инициализировалась.

Comment: Если просто написать matrix = new float* [n]; то оно всё равно будет неинициализироваться. Как тогда исправить?

Comment: Починил, приравняв к изначально созданной матрице 0 и поставив matrix = new float* [n]; в if

НО теперь оно просто запоминает значения и после повторного запуска и выбрав 1 пункт, оно сразу вводит все элементы и выводит решение. Как мне теперь сбросить что-ли значения, чтобы я сам по-новому воводил?

Comment: После какого повторного запуска? После повторного запуска программы?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос непонятен. Вот так всё работает правильно.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m;
    char d = '9'; //для меню
    float** matrix = nullptr;
    
    while(d > '3' || d < '1')
    {
        cout << " 1- ручной ввод \n 2- ввод из файла \n 3- выход \n введите: ";
        cin >> d;
        cout << endl;
        if (d > '3' || d < '1')
            cout << "правильно выберите пункт меню и введите число " << endl;
    }

    if (d == '3') { return 0; }
    if (d == '2') { return 0; }

    if (d == '1') //ручной ввод данных в матрицу
    {
        cout << "Количество уравнений: ";
        cin >> n;
        cout << "Количество переменных: ";
        cin >> m;
        m += 1;
        
        //создаем массив
        matrix = new float* [n];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            matrix[i] = new float[m];
        
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) //инициализируем
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                cout << " Элемент " << "[" << i + 1 << " , " << j + 1 << "]: ";
                cin >> matrix[i][j];
            }
    } 
    
    //выводим массив
    cout << "расширенная матрица" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " "; // Здесь возникает ошибка из вопроса
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    // освобождаем выделенную память
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        delete[] matrix[i];
    delete[] matrix;
    return 0;
}
```